# JAR Hell Hacks for Non-OSGi Developers

Tags: java, jar, osgi, dll

**Edit**: After reviewing the play, the example I used below is a *tad* misleading. I am looking for the case where I have two **3rd party jars** (not homegrown jars where I have access to the source code) that both depend on different versions of the same jar.

---

**Original:**
So I've recently familiarized myself with what OSGi is, and what ("JAR Hell") problems it addresses at its core. And, as intrigued as I am with it (and plan on migrating somewhere down the road), I just don't have it in me to begin learning what it will take to bring my projects over to it.

So, I'm now lamenting: if JAR hell happens to me, how do I solve this sans OSGi?

Obviously, the solution would almost *have* to involve writing my own `ClassLoader`, but I'm having a tough time visualizing how that would manifest itself, and more importantly, how that would solve the problem. I did some research and the consensus was that you have to write your own ClassLoader for every JAR you produce, but since I'm already having a tough time seeing that forest through the trees, that statement isn't sinking in with me.

Can someone provide a concrete example of how writing my own ClassLoader would put a band-aid on this gaping wound (I know, I know, the only real solution is OSGi)?

Say I write a new JAR called `SuperJar-1.0.jar` that does all sorts of amazing stuff. Say my `SuperJar-1.0.jar` has two other dependencies, `Fizz-1.0.jar` and `Buzz-1.0.jar`. Both `Fizz` and `Buzz` jars depend on `log4j`, except `Fizz-1.0.jar` depends on `log4j-1.2.15.jar`, whereas `Buzz-1.0.jar` depends on `log4j-1.2.16.jar`. Two different versions of the same jar.

**How could a ClassLoader-based solution resolve this (in a nutshell)?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're asking this question from an "I'm building an app, how do I avoid this" problem rather than a "I need this particular solution" angle, I would strongly prefer the Maven approach - namely, to only resolve a single version of any given dependency.  In the case of log4j 1.2.15 -> 1.2.16, this will work fine - you can include only 1.2.16.  Since the older version is API compatible (it's just a patch release) it's extremely likely that Fizz 1.0 won't even notice that it's using a newer version than it expected.

You'll find that doing this will probably be *way* easier to debug issues with (nothing confuses me like having multiple versions of even classes or static fields floating around!  Who knows which one you're dealing with!) and doesn't need any clever class loader hacks.

Comment: Note that this won't help you if you have truly incompatible version upgrades (e.g. Baz 1.0.0 -> 2.0.0 with backwards-incompatible changes).  You'd have to go an OSGI-like route or repackage the old jar into a new package.

Comment: Exactly. Yes this is a hypothetical and I'm interested in non-OSGi solutions. @Steven - can you elaborate on how/why repackaging the old jar could fix a truly-incompatible scenario?

Comment: Incidentally if the *only* reason you want to use OSGi is to get multiple versions of a library at the same time, I wouldn't bother. Multiple versions are confusing, and even in OSGi the support for this is limited. Far better to just do what it takes to get everybody compatible with one version. (BTW I'm not saying "don't use OSGi"... as you know I'm a huge advocate of OSGi. Just use it for the right reasons.)

Comment: What if I am using two 3rd party jars that are depending on different versions of, say, log4j? In this case I can't refactor the code to be compatible with the same log4j version.

Comment: @Mara: repackaging means manipulating the Java language packages. That is, you would move the log4j classes from the version Fizz uses from the org.log4j package into the fizz.org.log4j package, and the log4j classes from the version Buzz uses into buzz.org.log4j. You then change the references to org.log4j accordingly in the (byte)code of Fizz and Buzz. In your own code, you can automate this using the [Maven Shade plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/class-relocation.html). For third party libraries,  [JarJar](http://code.google.com/p/jarjar/) could be better.

Answer (score 3):

But, this is exactly what all the appservers out there have to deal with. Pretend that your Fizz and Buzz are web applications (WARs), and Super-Jar is you appserver. Super-Jar will arrange a class loader for each web app that "breaks" the normal delegation model, i.e. it will look locally (down) before looking up the hierarchy. Go read about it in any of the appservers's documentation. For example http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19798-01/821-1752/beade/index.html.

Comment: So @forty-two, am I correct to understand that (on GlassFish) I would just need to write my own ClassLoader, and if GlassFish sees a JAR/WAR that breaks the delegation model, it looks to see if there are any child ClassLoaders that can handle the resolution? If so, I assume these "child" ClassLoaders have to be included in the WARs themselves, yes?

Comment: No, I meant to say that your problem is solved by classloaders that breaks the normal delegation model. As an example of a solution to this problem, I choosed what app servers already do.

Comment: That works until you have a requirement to have one single webapp that has transitive dependencies on incompatible JARs.  In particular, right now I'm looking at a problem which requires me to include netty-3.2.2 and netty-3.6.1 in the same webapp, and they are API-incompatible.

Answer (score 0):

**Use log4j-1.2.16**. It only contains bugfixes wrt 1.2.15.

If Fizz breaks with 1.2.16, **fork and patch it**, then submit those patches back to the author of Fizz.

The alternative of creating custom classloaders with special delegation logic is very complex and likely to cause you many problems. I don't see why you would want to do this rather than just use OSGi. Have you considered creating an embedded OSGi framework, so you don't have to convert your whole application?

Comment: Is every library expected to be free software now? You can't "fork and patch" a black box.

Comment: @PedroLamarão: Agreed. If a library is broken and you can't patch it, then it's best just not to use it at all.

Comment: In context, no library is broken; it just depends on some software A version 1, while another library depends on A version 2.